# Sorting result set from a select using dense_rank()

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, t-sql

This query is returning the results that I require but I need to sort based on dateCreated not the job column used in the dense_rank()

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY job) AS denseRank,
        isnp.interviewSchedule AS interviewSchedule, 
        isnp.job AS job
        ,isnp.dateCreated
    FROM IvSchedule isnp
        JOIN Post p 
            ON p.id = isnp.job
        JOIN IvSchedule i 
            ON i.id = isnp.interviewSchedule
    ORDER BY denseRank OFFSET 0 rows
) x
WHERE denseRank > 0 AND denseRank <= 8
```

The results returned are (which is correct):

```
2017-03-23 14:30:30.150 1124    1815    1
2017-06-12 14:17:04.467 1126    1815    1
2017-05-17 17:39:02.430 1138    1817    2
2017-11-03 13:16:09.337 1149    1845    3
2017-09-15 10:04:05.350 1144    1846    4
```

But, I need them ordered by date, like so:

```
2017-03-23 14:30:30.150 1124    1815    1
2017-05-17 17:39:02.430 1138    1817    2
2017-06-12 14:17:04.467 1126    1815    1
2017-09-15 10:04:05.350 1144    1846    4
2017-11-03 13:16:09.337 1149    1845    3
```

Comment: Just add `order by dateCreated` to the outer query.

Comment: Aside: You needn't fear `Dense_Rank` returning a value < 1.

Comment: HABO I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that

Comment: `WHERE denseRank > 0` doesn't do much since the minimum value of `Dense_Rank()` is `1`.

Comment: HABO thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample query doesn’t have a presentation ORDER BY clause, and therefore, there’s no
assurance that the rows will be presented in any particular order. The window order clause
only determines ordering for the window function’s computation. If you invoke a window
function in your query but don’t specify a presentation ORDER BY clause, there’s no guarantee
that the rows will be presented in the same order as the window function’s ordering.
If you need such a guarantee, you need to add a presentation ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY job) AS denseRank,
        isnp.interviewSchedule AS interviewSchedule, 
        isnp.job AS job
        ,isnp.dateCreated
    FROM IvSchedule isnp
        JOIN Post p 
            ON p.id = isnp.job
        JOIN IvSchedule i 
            ON i.id = isnp.interviewSchedule
    ORDER BY denseRank OFFSET 0 rows
) x
WHERE denseRank > 1 AND denseRank <= 8

ORDER BY x.dateCreated
```

Comment: Sandra, I didn't fully understand the inner and outer order by, thank you for clarifying that